# How to Validate Output Binary During/After Compilation on Platform without ECC Memory

Tags: compiler, error-handling, build-system, compilation, error-detection

On a platform with ECC memory, you can assure the compiled binary is 100% legit with EDAC daemon. (single-bit error will be corrected automatically, and multi-bit error will be logged so you can just re-run the compilation).

But on a platform without ECC memory, you cannot guarantee that the output binary is legit.

It leads to a conclusion that if you are going to release that binary to the public or the application output needs to be accurate (like scientific computation or embedded), and the platform does not have ECC memory, then you have to compile twice for each compilation in order to check the difference between two outputs. (since there is almost 0% chance that the flipped part is same between two outputs)

I am curious about, for this aspect, what developers usually do for this problem. Do they just use a build system with ECC memory? Do they use that build system for generating debug binaries too? Or do they just use redundant, software approaches like above?

Comment: Have you done a full system analysis of your entire pipeline from code to deployment on the final systems and confirmed that this is a more significant issue than the myriad of other issues which exist? If not, **you're worrying about the wrong thing**.

Comment: You build it multiple times and compare the binaries.

Comment: I think very, very few developers have ever cared about this; most of the time it's a huge effort to even get a reproducible build out of the tools, because so many things like embedding the current time somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

> I am curious about, for this aspect, what developers usually do for this problem.

They consider it so incredibly unlikely that they don't waste any time thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect most commercial software to be built by a build-server managed by a continuous integration system. Such servers would normally be equipped with ECC memory by default. The build would then be tested, and that would very likely reveal any single bit errors.

In general the risk of undetected single bit errors would be insignificant compared to the risk of most other causes of bugs. So there is really not something to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve had a computer once with defective memory. From that experience, I can assure you, if you run the app, you’ll know.